# Strategies for Hosting E-learning SWFs

Tags: hosting, flash

Our training department has developed a number of interactive training videos that are in SWF format.  Is it common to use a different dedicated host for large numbers of SWFs (like is often done with Video) or are SWFs usually light enough weight that they can be hosted on the same platform as the main site without causing too much additional impact on things?

Please pardon my ignorance here... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would think the biggest impact you're going to see on your servers (aside from disk space required for storage of the SWF files) is the bandwidth consumed as people download these videos from your servers.